# include() doesn't work when my page has GET param

Tags: php, html

I have a `header.php` file containing my DOCTYPE and all my links/scripts.

I use

```
<?php
// HTML DOCTYPE insert
include 'header.php';
?>
```

at top of all my pages to have only one header for everyone, and it works fine.

Now, I have another page that get from a database a summary of my products information. When someone click on the "read more" link:

```
<p>
    <a href="display_product.php/?id='$myProductId'">read more...</a>
</p>
```

another page opens with the full information displayed...
Actually that works...

BUT on my new page (`display_product.php/id=[anynumber]`) my included file doesn't work. So I have no nav bar, no scripts, no stylesheet. Only the text from my database.

AND the weird thing is that when I copy/paste the HTML of my generated `display_product` page and launch it on my browser, it works... O-o
So the generated code is good.

AND the second weird thing is that when I get rid of the `/?id...` my layout works fine (but I have no text anymore, of course)

Does one of you have an idea why this crazy things happens?

Comment: remove the slash from `/?id`

Comment: You included correctly the header in the orher page?

Comment: Hi guys, Thanks very much Fred -ii this was it. it works perfectly.
Thanks sergiodebcn for your concerne.

Comment: so... problem solved I take it.

Comment: @JulienSegreto I decided to post an answer below since other answers were given, should you wish to accept and close the question properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"Hi guys, Thanks very much Fred -ii this was it. it works perfectly. Thanks sergiodebcn for your concerne."*

Since other answers were given and did not solve the actual problem, am posting my comment to an answer, in order to close the question.

- Remove the slash from `/?id`

The slash is trying to instruct the server to probably find a folder after a filename, which technically looks like is what's happening here.

Answer (score -1):

The ultimate solution for `include` and `require` functions with path issues, is to use the absolute filesystem path to the file that you want to include or require.

i.e you may say:

```
include("C:\\www\\app\\incs\\header.php");
```

**Hint**
To learn how to set the absolute path for include dynamically for your project, check the source code of two files of [cakephp](/questions/tagged/cakephp) framework:

- index.php
- webroot/index.php